# update firebase data after doing calculations

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I'm using Firebase as the db for my Ionic 2 app.

[image]

I wrote the following method to update all age fields in all child nodes to the value of 7 (for testing purposes):

```
  multiupdate(){
  var pc;

  this.memberProfileref.child('/members/').once('value',(snapshot)=> {

      snapshot.forEach(child=> {

          this.setAge(child.key);     // Will update all the age fields to 7 (works well)

          return false;
      });   
   });
}

setAge(UserId){
    this.memberProfile.child(UserId).update({
       age:7
    });
}
```

The above code is working well.

Insted of updating the age value, I now need to do a calculation and then an update.

I need to get **duedate** from Firebase, using the following method and calculate the duration based on today:

```
setduration(lastday){
   var today= moment().format('L');
      var durationd = moment(lastday).diff(moment(today));
      var dd=moment.duration(durationd).as('days');
     console.log(dd);
}
```

But when I call the method [just as I did with the setAgemethod()], it can't get the result. How to change the code to solve this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you pass to setduration? Is it `duedate`?
 What do you see in the output with `conlose.log(dd)`? Also, I would use `moment().valueOf()` to compare two timestamps.

Comment: @Ari 7 Thanks for replying.Yeah i need to goto through the all chidnodes one by one and take the **duedate** ,then pass it to the method **setduration()**  and get the duration.after that, update the field **duration**.in firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to emit the duration of each node by considering the already available duedate in the database. Check my code below and see how I called your method.

```
 multiupdate(){
      var pc;

      this.memberProfileref.child('/members/').once('value',(snapshot)=> {

          snapshot.forEach(child=> {

              this.setAge(child.key); // Will update all the age fields to 7 (works well)
              this.setduration(child.val().duedate); //<-- call your method like this

              return false;
          });   
       });
    }

    setAge(UserId){
        this.memberProfile.child(UserId).update({
           age:7
        });
    }

    setduration(lastday){
       var today= moment().format('L');
          var durationd = moment(lastday).diff(moment(today));
          var dd=moment.duration(durationd).as('days');
         console.log(dd);
    }
```

Comment: That's exactly what i needed.now its working fine.Thanks.